# How do I run all Python unit tests in a directory?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I have a directory that contains my Python unit tests. Each unit test module is of the form **test_*.py**. I am attempting to make a file called **all_test.py** that will, you guessed it, run all files in the aforementioned test form and return the result. I have tried two methods so far; both have failed. I will show the two methods, and I hope someone out there knows how to actually do this correctly.

For my first valiant attempt, I thought "If I just import all my testing modules in the file, and then call this `unittest.main()` doodad, it will work, right?" Well, turns out I was wrong.

```
import glob
import unittest

testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
test_file_strings = glob.glob('test_*.py')
module_strings = [str[0:len(str)-3] for str in test_file_strings]

if __name__ == "__main__":
     unittest.main()
```

This did not work, the result I got was:

```
$ python all_test.py 

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

For my second try, I though, ok, maybe I will try to do this whole testing thing in a more "manual" fashion. So I attempted to do that below:

```
import glob
import unittest

testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
test_file_strings = glob.glob('test_*.py')
module_strings = [str[0:len(str)-3] for str in test_file_strings]
[__import__(str) for str in module_strings]
suites = [unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName(str) for str in module_strings]
[testSuite.addTest(suite) for suite in suites]
print testSuite 

result = unittest.TestResult()
testSuite.run(result)
print result

#Ok, at this point I have a result
#How do I display it as the normal unit test command line output?
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This also did not work, but it seems so close!

```
$ python all_test.py 
<unittest.TestSuite tests=[<unittest.TestSuite tests=[<unittest.TestSuite tests=[<test_main.TestMain testMethod=test_respondes_to_get>]>]>]>
<unittest.TestResult run=1 errors=0 failures=0>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I seem to have a suite of some sort, and I can execute the result. I am a little concerned about the fact that it says I have only `run=1`, seems like that should be `run=2`, but it is progress. But how do I pass and display the result to main? Or how do I basically get it working so I can just run this file, and in doing so, run all the unit tests in this directory?

Comment: did you ever try running the tests from an test instance object?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814211/4754881) for a solution with an example file structure.

Answer (score 722, accepted):

With Python 2.7 and higher you don't have to write new code or use third-party tools to do this; recursive test execution via the command line is built-in.  Put an `__init__.py` in your test directory and:

```
python -m unittest discover <test_directory>
# or
python -m unittest discover -s <directory> -p '*_test.py'
```

You can read more in the [python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface)
or [python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) unittest documentation.

Comment: problems include: ImportError: Start directory is not importable:

Comment: At least with Python 2.7.8 on Linux neither command line invocation gives me recursion. My project has several subprojects whose unit tests live in respective "unit_tests/<subproject>/python/" directories. If I specify such a path the unit tests for that subproject are run, but with just "unit_tests" as test directory argument no tests are found (instead of all tests for all subprojects, as I hoped). Any hint?

Comment: About recursion: The first command without a <test_directory> defaults to "." and recurses to *submodules*. That is, all tests directories you want discovered needs to have a __init__.py. If they do, they will get found by the discover command. Just tried it, it worked.

Comment: did you ever try running the tests from an test instance object?

Comment: This works for me even if I don't specify -s and -p args. Just write `python -m unittest discover`

Comment: My tests seem to require `-m pytest` to run.  The test functions are defined in the test file but there are no explicit function calls.  If I try `unittest discover` it finds zero tests.

Comment: Could you please update this for Python3? `__init__.py` files are deprecated in favor of namespace packages.

Comment: Related to @CameronHudson's comment, it worked for me without the `__init__.py` file, and I am using python3.7.

Comment: Is it possible to instruct unittest to run the tests discovered as modules (aka using the `-m` switch) specifying also the working dir? Otherwise we might run into import issues as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/77822594/281545

Answer (score 279):

In python 3, if you're using `unittest.TestCase`:

- You must have an empty (or otherwise) `__init__.py` file in your `test` directory (*must* be named `test/`)
- Your test files inside `test/` match the pattern `test_*.py`.

  - They can be inside a subdirectory under `test/`. Those subdirs can be named as anything, but they all need to have an `__init__.py` file in them
- Your test function names should start with `test_`. Ex: `test_text_matcher`

Then, you can run all the tests with:

```
python -m unittest
```

Done! A solution less than 100 lines. Hopefully another python beginner saves time by finding this.

Comment: Note that by default it only searches for tests in filenames beginning with "test"

Comment: That's correct, the original question referred to the fact that "Each unit test module is of the form test_*.py.", so this answer in direct reply. I've now updated the answer to be more explicit

Comment: Thanks, that what was missing for me to use Travis Bear's answer.

Comment: In test/ folder, OK: `python3 ./deeply/nested/test_example.py`
But this shows import errors: `python3 -m unittest` Why?

Comment: I also needed to add the __init__.py file to each subfolder for it to work, otherwise great. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your answer to include that the subdirectories need to be packages as well, so that you need to add an __init__.py file to the subdirectories inside the test directory?

Comment: This works but subdir does not need to be named "test"

Comment: Since `unittest` version 3.2 you could also use the new keyword [discover](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) to discover all existing unit tests: `python -m unittest discover`

Comment: `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`, literally, how do I test a module that is not inside the `test/` folder? I'm aw-d that nobody seems to have this issue

Comment: I had to name my test directory as `tests` instead of `test` for the given command (`python -m unittest`) to work. If I name it `test`, I get some import errors

Answer (score 111):

You could use a test runner that would do this for you.  [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is very good for example.  When run, it will find tests in the current tree and run them.

Updated:

Here's some code from my pre-nose days.  You probably don't want the explicit list of module names, but maybe the rest will be useful to you.

```
testmodules = [
    'cogapp.test_makefiles',
    'cogapp.test_whiteutils',
    'cogapp.test_cogapp',
    ]

suite = unittest.TestSuite()

for t in testmodules:
    try:
        # If the module defines a suite() function, call it to get the suite.
        mod = __import__(t, globals(), locals(), ['suite'])
        suitefn = getattr(mod, 'suite')
        suite.addTest(suitefn())
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        # else, just load all the test cases from the module.
        suite.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(t))

unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Comment: Is the advantage of this approach over just explicitly importing all of your test modules in to one test_all.py module and calling unittest.main() that you can optionally declare a test suite in some modules and not in others?

Comment: I tried out nose and it works perfectly. It was easy to install and run in my project. I was even able to automate it with a few lines of script, running inside a virtualenv. +1 for nose!

Comment: Not always doable: sometimes importing structure of the project can lead to nose getting confused if it tries to run the imports on modules.

Comment: Note that [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has been "in maintenance mode for the past several years" and it is currently advised to use [nose2](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose2), [pytest](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), or just plain [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) / [unittest2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) for new projects.

Comment: did you ever try running the tests from an test instance object?

Answer (score 93):

This is now possible directly from unittest: [unittest.TestLoader.discover](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover).

```
import unittest
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
start_dir = 'path/to/your/test/files'
suite = loader.discover(start_dir)

runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(suite)
```

Comment: I have tried this method also, have couple tests, but works perfectly. Excellent!!! But I'm curious I have only 4 tests. Together they run 0.032s, but when I use this method to run them all, i get result `....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK` Why? The difference, where it comes from?

Comment: I am having trouble running a file that looks like this from the command line. How should it be invoked?

Comment: `python file.py`

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Just set it in your test/ dir and then set the start_id = "./" . IMHO, this answer is now (Python 3.7) the accepted way!

Comment: You can change the last line to ´res = runner.run(suite); sys.exit(0 if res.wasSuccessful() else 1)´ if you want a correct exit code

Answer (score 33):

Well by studying the code above a bit (specifically using `TextTestRunner` and `defaultTestLoader`), I was able to get pretty close. Eventually I fixed my code by also just passing all test suites to a single suites constructor, rather than adding them "manually", which fixed my other problems. So here is my solution.

```
import glob
import unittest

test_files = glob.glob('test_*.py')
module_strings = [test_file[0:len(test_file)-3] for test_file in test_files]
suites = [unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(test_file) for test_file in module_strings]
test_suite = unittest.TestSuite(suites)
test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(test_suite)
```

Yeah, it is probably easier to just use nose than to do this, but that is besides the point.

Comment: good, it works fine for the current directory, how to invoke the sub-directly ?

Comment: Larry, see the new answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24562019/104143) for recursive test discovery

Comment: did you ever try running the tests from an test instance object?

Answer (score 29):

If you want to run all the tests from various test case classes and you're happy to specify them explicitly then you can do it like this:

```
from unittest import TestLoader, TextTestRunner, TestSuite
from uclid.test.test_symbols import TestSymbols
from uclid.test.test_patterns import TestPatterns

if __name__ == "__main__":

    loader = TestLoader()
    tests = [
        loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(test)
        for test in (TestSymbols, TestPatterns)
    ]
    suite = TestSuite(tests)

    runner = TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    runner.run(suite)
```

where `uclid` is my project and `TestSymbols` and `TestPatterns` are subclasses of `TestCase`.

Comment: From the [unittest.TestLoader docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader): "Normally, there is no need to create an instance of this class; the unittest module provides an instance that can be shared as unittest.defaultTestLoader." Also since `TestSuite` accepts an _iterable_ as an argument, you can construct said iterable in a loop to avoid repeating `loader.loadTestsFromTestCase`.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist your second point in particular is nice.  I'd change the code to include but I can't test it.  (First mod would make it look like too much like Java for my liking.. though I realize I'm being irrational (screw them an their camel case variable names)).

Comment: This is my fav, very clean.  Was able to package this and make it an argument in my regular command line.

Answer (score 15):

I have used the `discover` method and an overloading of `load_tests` to achieve this result in a (minimal, I think) number lines of code:

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
''' Discover and load all unit tests in all files named ``*_test.py`` in ``./src/``
'''
    suite = TestSuite()
    for all_test_suite in unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('src', pattern='*_tests.py'):
        for test_suite in all_test_suite:
            suite.addTests(test_suite)
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Execution on fives something like

```
Ran 27 tests in 0.187s
OK
```

Comment: this is available for python2.7 only, I guess

Comment: @larrycai Maybe, I am usually on Python 3, sometimes Python 2.7. The question was not tied to a specific version.

Comment: I'm on Python 3.4 and discover returns a suite, making the loop redundant.

Comment: For future Larry's: "Many new features were added to unittest in Python 2.7, including test discovery. [unittest2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) allows you to use these features with earlier versions of Python."

Answer (score 9):

I tried various approaches but all seem flawed or I have to makeup some code, that's annoying.   But there's a convinient way under linux, that is simply to find every test through certain pattern and then invoke them one by one.

```
find . -name 'Test*py' -exec python '{}' \;
```

and most importantly, it definitely works.

Answer (score 8):

In case of a *packaged* library or application, you don't want to do it. `setuptools` [will do it for you](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite).

> To use this command, your project’s tests must be wrapped in a `unittest` test suite by either a function, a TestCase class or method, or a module or package containing `TestCase` classes. If the named suite is a module, and the module has an `additional_tests()` function, it is called and the result (which must be a `unittest.TestSuite`) is added to the tests to be run. If the named suite is a package, *any submodules and subpackages are recursively added to the overall test suite*.

Just tell it where your root test package is, like:

```
setup(
    # ...
    test_suite = 'somepkg.test'
)
```

And run `python setup.py test`.

File-based discovery may be problematic in Python 3, unless you avoid relative imports in your test suite, because [`discover`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) uses file import. Even though it supports optional `top_level_dir`, but I had some infinite recursion errors. So a simple solution for a non-packaged code is to put the following in `__init__.py` of your test package (see [load_tests Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol)).

```
import unittest

from . import foo, bar


def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(foo))
    suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(bar))

    return suite
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but what worked for me now (in 2019) is:

```
python -m unittest *_test.py
```

All my test files are in the same folder as the source files and they end with `_test`.

Answer (score 4):

I use PyDev/LiClipse and haven't really figured out how to run all tests at once from the GUI. (edit: you right click the root test folder and choose `Run as -> Python unit-test`

This is my current workaround:

```
import unittest

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    return loader.discover('.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I put this code in a module called `all` in my test directory. If I run this module as a unittest from LiClipse then all tests are run. If I ask to only repeat specific or failed tests then only those tests are run. It doesn't interfere with my commandline test runner either (nosetests) -- it's ignored.

You may need to change the arguments to `discover` based on your project setup.

Comment: The names of all test files and test methods should start with "test_". Otherwise the command "Run as -> Python unit test" wont find them.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of [Stephen Cagle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1735277/104143) I added support for nested test modules.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import unittest

def all_test_modules(root_dir, pattern):
    test_file_names = all_files_in(root_dir, pattern)
    return [path_to_module(str) for str in test_file_names]

def all_files_in(root_dir, pattern):
    matches = []

    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_dir):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, pattern):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

    return matches

def path_to_module(py_file):
    return strip_leading_dots( \
        replace_slash_by_dot(  \
            strip_extension(py_file)))

def strip_extension(py_file):
    return py_file[0:len(py_file) - len('.py')]

def replace_slash_by_dot(str):
    return str.replace('\\', '.').replace('/', '.')

def strip_leading_dots(str):
    while str.startswith('.'):
       str = str[1:len(str)]
    return str

module_names = all_test_modules('.', '*Tests.py')
suites = [unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(mname) for mname 
    in module_names]

testSuite = unittest.TestSuite(suites)
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1)
runner.run(testSuite)
```

The code searches all subdirectories of `.` for `*Tests.py` files which are then loaded. It expects each `*Tests.py` to contain a single class `*Tests(unittest.TestCase)` which is loaded in turn and executed one after another.

This works with arbitrary deep nesting of directories/modules, but each directory in between needs to contain an empty `__init__.py` file at least. This allows the test to load the nested modules by replacing slashes (or backslashes) by dots (see `replace_slash_by_dot`).

Answer (score 3):

I just created a discover.py file in my base test directory and added import statements for anything in my sub directories. Then discover is able to find all my tests in those directories by running it on discover.py

```
python -m unittest discover ./test -p '*.py'
```

```
# /test/discover.py
import unittest

from test.package1.mod1 import XYZTest
from test.package1.package2.mod2 import ABCTest
...

if __name__ == "__main__"
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Encountered the same issue.

The solution is to add an empty `__init__.py` to each folder and uses `python -m unittest discover -s`

Project Structure

```
tests/
  __init__.py
  domain/
    value_object/
      __init__.py
      test_name.py
    __init__.py
  presentation/
    __init__.py
    test_app.py
```

And running the command

```bash
python -m unittest discover -s tests/domain
```

To get the expected outcome

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.007s
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Test discovery seems to be a complete subject, there is some dedicated framework to test discovery :

- [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [Py.Test](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#python-test-discovery)

More reading here : https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTestingToolsTaxonomy

Answer (score 1):

This BASH script will execute the python unittest test directory from ANYWHERE in the file system, no matter what working directory you are in: its working directory always be where that `test` directory is located.

**ALL TESTS, independent $PWD**

unittest Python module is sensitive to your current directory, unless you tell it where (using `discover -s` option).

This is useful when staying in the `./src` or `./example` working directory and you need a quick overall unit test:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
this_program="$0"
dirname="`dirname $this_program`"
readlink="`readlink -e $dirname`"

python -m unittest discover -s "$readlink"/test -v
```

**SELECTED TESTS, independent $PWD**

I name this utility file: `runone.py` and use it like this:

```sh
runone.py <test-python-filename-minus-dot-py-fileextension>
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
this_program="$0"
dirname="`dirname $this_program`"
readlink="`readlink -e $dirname`"

(cd "$dirname"/test; python -m unittest $1)
```

No need for a `test/__init__.py` file to burden your package/memory-overhead during production.

Answer (score 0):

I have no package and as mentioned on this page, this is creating issue while issing dicovery. So, I used the following solution. All the test result will be put in a given output folder.

*RunAllUT.py*:

```
"""
The given script is executing all the Unit Test of the project stored at the
path %relativePath2Src% currently fixed coded for the given project. 

Prerequired:
    - Anaconda should be install
    - For the current user, an enviornment called "mtToolsEnv" should exists
    - xmlrunner Library should be installed
"""

import sys
import os
import xmlrunner
from Repository import repository 

relativePath2Src="./../.."
pythonPath=r'"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.conda\envs\YourConfig\python.exe"' 
outputTestReportFolder=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+r'\test-reports' #subfolder in current file path

class UTTesting():
    """
    Class tto run all the UT of the project
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initiate instance

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        self.projectRepository = repository() 
        self.UTfile = [] #List all file
    
    def retrieveAllUT(self):
        """
        Generate the list of UT file in the project

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        print(os.path.realpath(relativePath2Src))
        self.projectRepository.retriveAllFilePaths(relativePath2Src)
        #self.projectRepository.printAllFile() #debug
        for file2scan in self.projectRepository.devfile:
            if file2scan.endswith("_UT.py"):
                self.UTfile.append(file2scan)
                print(self.projectRepository.devfilepath[file2scan]+'/'+file2scan)
                
    
    def runUT(self,UTtoRun):
        """
        Run a single UT

        Parameters
        ----------
        UTtoRun : String
            File Name of the UT

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        print(UTtoRun)
        if UTtoRun in self.projectRepository.devfilepath:
            UTtoRunFolderPath=os.path.realpath(os.path.join(self.projectRepository.devfilepath[UTtoRun]))
            UTtoRunPath = os.path.join(UTtoRunFolderPath, UTtoRun)
        print(UTtoRunPath)
        
        #set the correct execution context & run the test
        os.system(" cd " + UTtoRunFolderPath + \
                  " & " + pythonPath + " " + UTtoRunPath + " " + outputTestReportFolder )
        
        
    def runAllUT(self):
        """
        Run all the UT contained in self
        The function "retrieveAllUT" sjould ahve been performed before

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        for UTfile in self.UTfile:
            self.runUT(UTfile)
                
    
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    undertest=UTTesting()
    undertest.retrieveAllUT()
    undertest.runAllUT()
```

In my project specific, I have a class that I used in other script. This might be an overkill for your usecase.

*Repository.py*

```
import os

class repository():
    """
    Class that decribed folder and file in a repository 
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initiate instance

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        self.devfile = [] #List all file
        self.devfilepath = {} #List all file paths

    def retriveAllFilePaths(self,pathrepo):
        """
        Retrive all files and their path in the class

        Parameters
        ----------
        pathrepo : Path used for the parsin

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(pathrepo):
            for file_name in files:
                self.devfile.append(file_name)
                self.devfilepath[file_name] = path
                
    def printAllFile(self):
        """
        Display all file with paths

        Parameters
        ----------
        def printAllFile : TYPE
            DESCRIPTION.

        Returns
        -------
        None.

        """
        for file_loop in self.devfile:
            print(self.devfilepath[file_loop]+'/'+file_loop)
```

In your test files, you need to have a main like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import xmlrunner
    import sys
    
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        outputFolder = sys.argv.pop() #avoid conflic with unittest.main
    else:
        outputFolder = r'test-reports'
    print("Report will be created and store there: " + outputFolder)
    
    unittest.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output=outputFolder))
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is my approach by creating [a wrapper](https://github.com/mycognitive/ads_tests/blob/master/selenium/run_tests.py) to run tests from the command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, sys, unittest, argparse, inspect, logging

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Parse arguments.
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument("-?", "--help",     action="help",                        help="show this help message and exit" )
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",  action="store_true", dest="verbose",  help="increase output verbosity" )
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug",    action="store_true", dest="debug",    help="show debug messages" )
    parser.add_argument("-h", "--host",     action="store",      dest="host",     help="Destination host" )
    parser.add_argument("-b", "--browser",  action="store",      dest="browser",  help="Browser driver.", choices=["Firefox", "Chrome", "IE", "Opera", "PhantomJS"] )
    parser.add_argument("-r", "--reports-dir", action="store",   dest="dir",      help="Directory to save screenshots.", default="reports")
    parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Load files from the arguments.
    for filename in args.files:
        exec(open(filename).read())

    # See: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/88655/15346
    def make_suite(tc_class):
        testloader = unittest.TestLoader()
        testnames = testloader.getTestCaseNames(tc_class)
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        for name in testnames:
            suite.addTest(tc_class(name, cargs=args))
        return suite

    # Add all tests.
    alltests = unittest.TestSuite()
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__]):
        if inspect.isclass(obj) and name.startswith("FooTest"):
            alltests.addTest(make_suite(obj))

    # Set-up logger
    verbose = bool(os.environ.get('VERBOSE', args.verbose))
    debug   = bool(os.environ.get('DEBUG', args.debug))
    if verbose or debug:
        logging.basicConfig( stream=sys.stdout )
        root = logging.getLogger()
        root.setLevel(logging.INFO if verbose else logging.DEBUG)
        ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        ch.setLevel(logging.INFO if verbose else logging.DEBUG)
        ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(name)s: %(message)s'))
        root.addHandler(ch)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

    # Run tests.
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(alltests)
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

For sake of simplicity, please excuse my non-[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) coding standards.

Then you can create BaseTest class for common components for all your tests, so each of your test would simply look like:

```
from BaseTest import BaseTest
class FooTestPagesBasic(BaseTest):
    def test_foo(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
```

To run, you simply specifying tests as part of the command line arguments, e.g.:

```
./run_tests.py -h http://example.com/ tests/**/*.py
```

Comment: most of this answer has nothing to do with test discovery (i.e logging, etc).  Stack Overflow is for answering questions, not showing off unrelated code.