# How do you create a python package with a built in "test/main.py" main function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, module, package

Desired directory tree:

```
Fibo
|-- src
|   `-- Fibo.py
`-- test
    `-- main.py
```

What I want is to call `python main.py` after cd'ing into test and executing main.py will run all the unit tests for this package.

Currently if I do:

```
import Fibo

def main():
    Fibo.fib(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get an error: "`ImportError: No module named Fibo`".

But if I do:

```
import sys

def main():
    sys.path.append("/home/tsmith/svn/usefuldsp/trunk/Labs/Fibo/src")
    import Fibo
    Fibo.fib(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This seems to fix my error. And I could move forward... but this isn't a python package. This is more of a "collection of files" approach.

**How would you setup your testing to work in this directory structure?**

Comment: Question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I want to import a module that lives at a fixed, relative location to the file I'm evaluating, I often do something like this:

```
try:
    import Fibo
except ImportError:
    import sys
    from os.path import join, abspath, dirname
    parentpath = abspath(join(dirname(__file__), '..'))
    srcpath = join(parentpath, 'src')
    sys.path.append(srcpath)
    import Fibo

def main():
    Fibo.fib(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want to be a good namespace-citizen, you could `del` the no longer needed symbols at the end of the `except` block.

Comment: what about if I want to make Fibo some sort of 'reusable library'?

Comment: If you want to make a module available globally without this sort of adaptive alteration of `sys.path` "just in case", then you need to use the PYTHONPATH environment variable, or install it in a global location that's already being searched. See the documentation for `distutils`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `/home/tsmith/svn/usefuldsp/trunk/Labs/Fibo/src` to your PYTHONPATH environment variable 
would allow you to write

```
import Fibo

def main():
    Fibo.fib(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and have it import `.../Fibo/src/Fibo.py` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way: create a symbolic link