# No module error when trying to run tests

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to base my project structure on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885). According to the answerer, all I need to do is structure my application like this:

```
project-name
    project_name
        __init__.py
        some_module.py
        some_other_module.py
    tests
        __init__.py
        test_some_module.py
        test_some_other_module.py
```

However, running `python3.5 -m unittest discover` results in this error:
`ImportError: No module named project_name`.

My `__init__.py` files are empty as I understood that would make python think everything was a package. I understand there is a way to do it using PYTHONPATH but I had also understood that there was no need to use PYTHONPATH if you followed this package system.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an easy fix, or do I need to use a different structure or system to run tests?

Comment: Where are you running your unittest command exactly

Comment: That was the issue, I was running the unittest from the wrong directory.

Comment: Where did you end up running your unit-tests from in the end?

Comment: The project-name directory. I was running from the tests directory before.

Comment: Ah ok! I understand. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

According this link from python Doc: [Python Module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

I believe do you need create a __init__.py file in the first project-name root dir.

```
project-name
__init__.py
project_name
    __init__.py
    some_module.py
    some_other_module.py
tests
    __init__.py
    test_some_module.py
    test_some_other_module.py
```