# CD command not working inside FOR loop?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I am new to batch programming.

The output of the following program:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd /d C:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
echo %cd%
FOR /F %%i IN (temp_list.txt) DO (
 echo i is %%i
 cd folder
 echo %cd%
)
cd folder
echo %cd%
pause
```

is:

```
C:\Users\arnab\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
i is e6slask2.default
C:\Users\arnab\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
i is random.default
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Users\arnab\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Users\arnab\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\folder
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I understand that the `FOR` logic is wrong (i effectively am doing `cd folder` twice, should be possible only unless there is a 'folder' inside a 'folder')

but why isn't the cd folder taking me to the `"C:\Users\abhagaba.ORADEV\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\folder"` for the first iteration in the `FOR` loop?

Does `CD` not work inside a `FOR` loop?

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, batch don't update variables inside a code block, but there must be a way to solve it. That's why `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` is pretty useful once working with `for`/`if` commands. The code will look like:

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d C:%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
echo %cd%
FOR /F %%i IN (temp_list.txt) DO (
    echo i is %%i
    cd folder
    echo !cd!
)
cd folder
echo %cd%
pause
```

Replace percent signs with exclamation marks (`%var% -> !var!`) will solve your problem. Don't worry about variables outside the code block, using old-style `%var%` will not affect the result.

Comment: I think you meant to use %%i instead of folder. Thanks for the solution.