# Python unittest failing to resolve import statements

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a file structure that looks like the following

```
project
    src
        __init__.py
        main.py
        module.py
        secondary.py
    test
        test_module.py
```

### module.py

```
import secondary
x = False
```

### secondary.py

```
pass
```

### test_module.py

```
from unittest import TestCase

from src import module

 class ModuleTest(TestCase):
    def test_module(self):
        self.assertTrue(module.x)
```

Invoking `python3 -m unittest discover` in `/project/` gives an error:

```
 File "/Users/Me/Code/project/test/test_module.py", line 6, in <module>
  from src import module
 File "/Users/Me/Code/project/src/module.py", line 1, in <module>
  import secondary
ImportError: No module named 'secondary'
```

What can I do so that `secondary.py` is imported without error?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure

Comment: You could specify that it's in the same directory by doing `import .secondary`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3 (and Python 2 with `from __future__ import absolute_import`), you must be explicit about what module you want when importing another module from the same package. The syntax you're using in `module.py` (`import secondary`) only works if `secondary` is a top-level module in a folder in the Python module search path.

To explicitly request a relative import from your own package, use `from . import secondary` instead. Or, make an absolute import, using the name of the package as well as the module (`from src import secondary`, or `import src.secondary` and use `src.secondary` elsewhere the module instead of just `secondary`).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of the test file

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

Note: Depending on the project structure we have to specify the root folder