# how python "import" actually works when using unittest?

Tags: python

Here is my folder structure:

```
.
├── mod
│   └── a.py
└── tests
    └── test_a.py

2 directories, 2 files
```

tests/test_a.py simply looks like this:

```
import unittest
from mod import a

class ATestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        print(a.a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

When I do unittest, surely everything is fine:

```
$ python -m unittest tests/test_a.py 
1
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

However, when I simply run tests/test_a.py as a python script, error happens:

```
$ python tests/test_a.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_a.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mod import a
ImportError: No module named 'mod'
```

My question is why, using unittest, mod becomes importable?

Comment: @czheo have you seen this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure

Does this help?

Comment: @shafaq Do you mean the unittest module modified "sys.path"? However, when I printed sys.path out in my test_a.py file, I didn't find it is modified.

Comment: It does the first item path[0]. Try printing `print os.path.abspath(sys.path[0])`. You will see it would give you the path to `mod` directory. While without `unittest` it would go to `test` directory. So `a` module is not traceable.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path here it is in documentation.

Comment: @shafaq Got it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned and discussed this question : [Running unittest with typical directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure?lq=1)

> The best solution in my opinion is to use the unittest command line interface which will add the directory to the sys.path so you don't have to (done in the TestLoader class).

Looking at the documentation: [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.

Try printing `print os.path.abspath(sys.path[0])` when using `python -m unittest tests.test_a` (in a function/method) and you will see `../mod` on your path and that is why `a` is located.

Now run `python tests/test_a.py` and `tests` directory would be on path hence `a` would not be located.