# pytest Interrupted: ImportError "No module named primes"

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I have changed the `sys.path` to `../mypkg` in the test_primes.py and it works when I execute it separately (without pytest) -

> python test_primes.py

But, when I do

> py.test

in the src, it doesn't work

**PLEASE CHECK OUT THE IMAGE FOR THE DETAILED ERROR**

[pytest image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IICeP.jpg)

Comment: You probably need `python -m unittest`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885/3025981

Comment: "in the source" - what is your current directory when you do that? "../mypkg" only works from one directory. Consider taking that out completely and setting an environment variable when you test. `PYTHONPATH=path/to/pkgroot:$PYTHONPATH py.test` on linuxy systems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it should work fine when you stop modifying `sys.path`, and actually import from your package instead: `from mypkg.primes import is_prime`.