# Trivial python import fails

Tags: python

I'm confused on why a simple absolute import is failing.  Following the Python [packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) tutorial, I have package with a single subpackage:

```
sound/
    __init__.py
    top.py
    formats/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
```

a.py contains:

```
def foo():
    print("foo")
```

b.py contains:

```
from a import foo

def bar():
    foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bar()
```

top.py contains:

```
from formats import b    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b.bar()
```

Both `__init__.py` files are empty.  From sound/formats/, running b prints `foo` as expected.  But from sound/, running top produces the error:

```
File ".../sound/top.py", line 1, in <module>
  from formats import b
File "...\sound\format\b.py", line 1, in <module>
  from a import foo
ImportError: No module named 'a'
```

(Note the strange appearance of forward slashes in the first line and back slashes in the second.  Python 3.5, Windows 7 Pro.)  This shouldn't be that complicated -- what syntax is necessary to allow b to consistently import a?

----- EDIT -----

[Running unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure) is the question I should have found before asking this one.  It also contains a great pointer to the [Python Project Howto](http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from .a import foo` since `a` is in the same directory as `b`?  If you want to be able to run `b` directly from `sound/formats`, you might need to mess with `__package__` (See [PEP-0366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)).

Comment: Nope - top works in that case, but b fails with "SystemError: Parent module ' ' not loaded, cannot perform relative import".

Comment: Right.  See my comment continuation about `__package__`.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just setting your PythonPath environment variable?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: I think you're confused about what absolute imports are. It looks like you're expecting an implicit relative import.

Comment: @mgilson, Yes, I was confused about the fact that running a file as a script yields different results than running the same file as a module.  From a script, an absolute `from a import foo` works properly because sys.path includes the folder containing a and b.  It would be nice if the default import hooks (PEP 302) automatically behaved as if the package root were always present in sys.path.  That way relative imports would work consistently regardless of whether a file is invoked as a script or a module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's really not how you should be running your code.

With Python packages you *shouldn't* be in the folder that contains the files when you're running the code. That'd be like going to `C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\http\`* and then running `py -3 server.py`. Ew. Don't do that.

Instead, use Python the way it expects to be used!

```
⚘ python --help | grep -e -m                                     
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

You're creating modules, but you want to be able to run them as a script. Turns out that you can do that!

```
> cd ../..
> dir
sound
> python -m sound.formats.b
foo
> python -m sound.top
foo
```

*<sup><sub>I think that's the path but it's been a while since Windows for me. If it's wrong, I'm just trying to make a point here!</sub></sup>

Comment: `grep -e -m` might be a little more idiomatic shell scripting, btw.

Comment: Using `grep` and a Windows path in the same post... But yap, the path is correct.

Comment: @linusg and I'm on a Mac. Go figure ;)

Comment: I have one subproject with some code and the unit tests for that code.  I have a second subproject that needs to import from the first.  Is there a best practice for creating unittests that aren't run from within the directory containing the code?  The example I was following had `test_foo.py` containing `if __name__ = "__main__": unittest.main()`.

Comment: I prefer to keep my unittests separate. In your case I would have `project/sound/` and `project/tests/`. Then in my tests directory, in my tests files, I would have `import sound` or possibly `from sound.format import a` or something to that effect. I also create a `venv` to install my project into.