# python.path.append() can't access 2 directories above - Windows10

Tags: sys.path

I'm trying to create a unit testing folder outside of the program itself. The structure of the program is as follows:

```
TheProgram
-- Folder_1
-- -- File_1.py

unittest
-- TestFolder1
-- -- TestFile_1.py
```

From TestFile_1.py the path accessing code was

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../TheProgram/Folder_1")
from File_1.py import *
```

The system couldn't find the Folder_1 directory. The following code was also tested but yielded the same result: `sys.path.insert(2, "TheProgram/Folder_1")`. Both the `TheProgram` and the `unittest` folders are in the same directory.

How do you access File_1.py from TestFile_1.py in this case?

Comment: Take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure

Comment: Thanks, I went through the link. The solutions didn't seem to be working on Windows 10.