# How to organize a python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am new to python and trying to figure out how to do things the "right way" and encountered the following problem:

My project has a structure that looks a little this:

```
├─packageA
│     functions.py
│     __init__.py
│
└─tests
      some_tests.py
```

`packageA/__init__.py` is empty.

`packageA/functions.py` looks like this:

```
def some_function(x):
    return x*x
```

And finally, `tests/some_tests.py`:

```
import packageA.functions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(packageA.functions.some_function(2))
```

If I run test.py using pycharm it works fine. However, when I open up a console and start it by running `python.exe ./tests/some_tests.py` I get

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tests\some_tests.py", line 1, in <module>
    import packageA.functions
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packageA'
```

While writing this, I figured out that pycharm adds source folders to PYTHONPATH - when I turn this off I get the same error. Is the folder structure above a sensible way to structure a python project? If not, how should it be organized instead?

Comment: You can leave your folder structure if it is if you use the standard `unittest` module for your tests. Then the tests can be run with `python -m unittest` from the root directory and the import of `packageA` succeeds. I am not sure why this works, while `python ./tests/some_tests.py` does not. Can someone enlighten me? Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885/6095394 gave me the answer: The `TestLoader` of the `unittest` module adds the package directory to `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. However, the accepted answer in a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) isn't ideal.

The [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158224/9209546) addresses your issue by explicitly adding the parent directory path at the start of your `sys.path` list.

```
import os, sys, inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0, parentdir) 

import packageA.functions
```