# How to setup project structure so unittest imports work?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a project that looks like this:

```
project/
  setup.py
  project/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
  test/
    __init__.py
    test_a.py
    test_b.py
```

and `b.py` contains the import statement `import a`.

Running `python -m unittest` or `python setup.py test`  from the `project` root directory results in `ModuleNotFoundError` when `test_b.py` tries to run `from project import b`.

As far as I can tell, this is nearly the exact setup as https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885/4190459 but it's not working. Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the relative module import `import a` that exists in `b.py`

For Python 3, this should be:

```
from . import a
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that python looked in the same directory as default, but apparently it's more complicated than that.

Comment: Yes, `import a` works in Python 2 where relative imports are default, but you need to be explicit about them in Python 3, hence `from . import a`

Comment: This seems to break running b.py from the command line, though. Doing `python b.py` results in `ImportError: cannot import name 'a'`.

Comment: That's because you're running `b.py` as a script, when it is a module in a package, and that breaks the relative import. There are some solutions to support both usages, which are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: Wow, what a mess. Thanks for the help. Running `python -m project.b` now seems to work. A bit wordy perhaps, but seems to be the "official" way of doing things. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement in b.py should be.

```
from project import a
```

Then in test_a.py you can do

```
import unittest
from project import a
from project import b


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        print(a.a_var)
        print(b.b_var)
        pass
```

you can then run your tests like

```
python -m unittest
a
b
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```