# How to get imports to work with python package and testing package

Tags: python, import, python-unittest

I'm struggling to get imports to work for my python project.  I've created a test project to illustrate my issue.  This is with Python 3.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
project/
  test.sh
  packageA/
     __init__.py
     moduleA.py
     test/
        __init__.py
        test_moduleA.py
```

The contents of test.sh is `python3 packageA/test/test_moduleA.py`

Both `__init__py` are empty.

This is `moduleA.py`:

```
class A:
  def doSomething(self):
    print("Did something")
```

This is 'test_moduleA.py`:

```
import unittest
from packageA.moduleA import A

class TestModuleA(unittest.TestCase):
  def testSomething(self):
    a = A()
    self.assertTrue(a.doSomething() == "Did Something")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run `test.sh` this is the error I get:

```
[project] $ ./test.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packageA/test/test_moduleA.py", line 2, in <module>
    from packageA.moduleA import A
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packageA'
[project] $
```

I have tried using the relative import in `test_moduleA.py' as follows:

`from ..moduleA import A`

In this case there error I get is shown below:

```
[project] $ ./test.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packageA/test/test_moduleA.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..moduleA import A
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
[project] $
```

How do I get this to work properly?  What is the Pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggested solution, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure) (see also [here](https://gist.github.com/tasdikrahman/2bdb3fb31136a3768fac)) and [this article](http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/python-unit-testing-structuring-your-project/).

First of all, move the test directory into the root of your project:

```
project/
  test.sh
  packageA/
     __init__.py
     moduleA.py
  test/
     __init__.py
     test_moduleA.py
```

Then, change the `test_moduleA.py` as follows (note the import):

```
import unittest
from packageA.moduleA import A


class TestModuleA(unittest.TestCase):
    def testSomething(self):
        a = A()
        self.assertTrue(a.do_something() == "Something was done")
```

The `test.sh` is this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST_PACKAGE="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

cd ${TEST_PACKAGE}
python3 -m unittest test.test_moduleA
```

I've changed also the a class in order to pass the test:

```
class A:
    def do_something(self):
        print("do_somwthing was called")
        return "Something was done"
```

Now, run `test.sh` and it should work as expected:

```
$ ./test.sh 
do_somwthing was called
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is an interesting solution.  I'll give it a try.  However, I think I would like to keep my test directory as a child of the package.  I'm going to likely have a number of sibling packages so keeping the tests under them helps to keep things organized.  How would this solution be modified for that?

Comment: This does the trick `python3 -m unittest packageA.test.test_moduleA`

Answer (score 0):

Using shell scripts to test/deploy python stuff isn't really a good idea, so I propose you instead replacing test.sh with `test.py`, whose content would be:

```
import unittest

testmodules = [
    'packageA.test.test_moduleA',
]

suite = unittest.TestSuite()

for t in testmodules:
    try:
        mod = __import__(t, globals(), locals(), ['suite'])
        suitefn = getattr(mod, 'suite')
        suite.addTest(suitefn())
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        suite.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(t))

unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Adding new tests to it would be quite easy, you'd just need to modify the testmodules list.

Comment: I intend to use something like gradle since this is part of a bigger project.  The shell script is just to help illustrate the problem.  I will try this solution and see how it goes.  Still it does not explain why my imports are not working.