# Where to put tests for subpackages in python?

Tags: python, testing, nested, package, directory-structure

When a python module has multiple subpackages, where should tests for features in those subpackages be placed?

I can see two ways it could be done:

- Create a separate `test` folder in each subpackage and place its tests there.
- Duplicate the package hierarchy in the top-level `test` folder, placing the tests for each subpackage in the corresponding folder.

However it's not clear which option should be preferred.

For a package `foo` arranged like this:

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  bar.py
  baz/
    __init__.py
    baz.py
```

Do I put the tests here?

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  bar.py
  baz/
    __init__.py
    baz.py
  test/
    __init__.py
    test_bar.py
    baz/
      __init__.py
      test_baz.py
```

Or here?

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  bar.py
  baz/
    __init__.py
    baz.py
    test/
      __init__.py
      test_baz.py
  test/
    __init__.py
    test_bar.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885/6529424

But it really comes down to preference/style or it depends on whatever framework you use to test your code.