# Python Pytest - Project structure and import statements

Tags: python, python-import, pytest, python-unittest, directory-structure

Assuming the following standard project structure

```
- project
-- src
---- __init__.py
---- script1.py
---- script2.py
---- module
---- __init__.py
------ helper.py
-- test
---- __init__.py
---- test_script1.py
---- test_script2.py
---- module
---- __init__.py
------ test_helper.py
```

the following imports in script1.py

```
import script2
from module import helper
```

and in test_script1.py

```
from src import script1
```

Calling the tests from the project directory with

```
python -m pytest tests
```

Fails, because when script1.py tries to import e.g. script2, the module will not be found because root is project/test that contains no src, throwing something like

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2'
```

Modifying script1.py the following way

```
from src import script2
from src.module import helper
```

would fix the import at test time, but it would break when trying to run script1, whose root folder is src (which doesn't contain itself).

I assume that this is a standard case, but I couldn't find a clean solution (meaning **not** relying on sys.path.append('src') ).

The solution pointed out in 
[Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)
does not take into account imports within the src folder.

My workaround at the moment is having the test folder inside src

```
- project
-- src
---- __init__.py
---- script1.py
---- script2.py
---- module
---- __init__.py
------ helper.py
---- test
------- __init__.py
------- test_script1.py
------- test_script2.py
------ module
------ __init__.py
-------- test_helper.py
```

and having inside of, g.e. test_script1.py the following import

```
import script1
```

but I want to keep the folder structure mentioned at the beginning.

I will think of you for any suggestion.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you manage to resolve this?