# Test not being executed from command line

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Below test works as expected when I execute from PyCharm but when I attempt to run `python TestData.py` from command line I receive :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestData.py", line 3, in <module>
    from service.DataAccessor import Data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'service'
```

When I try `python -m unittest`

I receive:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Both commands are run from `project` directory.

Project structure is:

```
project/service
 - DataAccessor.py
project/test
 - TestData.py
```

Code:

TestData.py :

```
    import unittest

    from service.DataAccessor import Data

    class TestData(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_get_data(self):
            print(Data.getDf(self))
            self.assertEqual(3, 3)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

DataAccessor.py:

```
import pandas as pd

class Data():

    def getDf(self):

        df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
        return df
```

Comment: Looks like `service` is not in the Python path. Either change the import to include `project` (I guess that is in the path), or add `service` to the path while running the tests.
Or you run the test from inside `project`, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from Java background I'm not 100% sure why this works but adding an empty `__init__.py` to the dirs: test & service and executed python -m unittest test.TestData executes the test.

Comment: Ah ok - the `__init__.py` marks the directories as python modules for the test or other python programs.