# How to write tests for a Python 3 project not installed by pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I have a project with a structure like this:

```
readme.md
requirements.txt
project/
    main.py
    helpers.py
    recording.py
```

I want to write some tests, for example `test_helpers.py` that will test the functionaility in `helpers.py`

I tried doing it like this:

```
readme.md
requirements.txt
project/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    helpers.py
    recording.py
tests/
    test_helpers.py
```

and in `test_helpers.py`:

```py
from ..project import helpers
```

But this throws an error:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

How would I go about importing things correctly?

I'm aware that I can add the directory using `sys.path.insert` but that seems quite hacky considering I would have to do it for every test*.py file?

Comment: For example: Move `tests` folder to the `project` folder and add another  `__iniit__.py` inside  `tests`

Comment: Run tests from outside folder, maybe use test discovery.

Comment: @progmatico moving it doesn't help, it still errors with `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: After the changes mentioned, try launching  `python -m unittest discover project.tests` issued from the `project` *parent folder*.

Comment: @progmatico I should have mentioned I'm using pytest, now I'm getting another error:
```python
project\tests\test_helpers.py:1: in <module>
    from .. import helpers
project\helpers.py:5: in <module>
    import config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'```
(I should mention theres another python file in the project folder called config.py that is imported by helpers.py)

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure/24266885#24266885) for unittests and [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/directory_structure.html) for pytests. Hope that helps.