# Python unit test cannot find module

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a question about how to correctly import module in python unit test module.
this is my directory structure

```
project -
        | _ Library _
        |            |_ TimeCalculator.py
        | _ Test _
                  |_ UnittestFile.py
```

and I want to test the function in TimeCalculator.py
so in UnittestFile.py I write

```
from .Library.TimeCalculator import TimeCalculator
```

but the error come out saying **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**
I want to ask how to import without setting the PATH in this case.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [python - Running unittest with typical test directory structure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure/24266885#24266885), you should create a `__init__.py` file in both folders, `Library` and `Test`.

For your specific structure:

```
project
├── Library
│   ├── __init__.py         # make it a package
│   └── TimeCalculator.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py         # also make test a package
    └── UnittestFile.py
```

Then, you should remove the first `.` from your import sentence:

```
from Library.TimeCalculator import TimeCalculator
```

**PD:** Not sure if is a repeated question, because the answer is almost the same than [python - Running unittest with typical test directory structure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure/24266885#24266885) but is sightly different because he has to remove the first `.`

Comment: I think that's a good duplicate target. The `.` just seems like a typo.