# What is the correct way to use unittest in python with the test modules in a directory inside the main package?

Tags: python

I am currently developing a python package with 3.7.1 and am trying to use unittest with a /test directory containing test modules, which will then contain multiple test cases. I am trying to use the following directory structure:

```
|_ app/
  |_ main.py
  |_ my_module/
             |_ MyPackage.py
  |_ test/
             |_ test_MyPackage.py
```

Inside test_MyPackage.py I am trying to import the required class from MyPackage using from my_module.MyPackage import MyClass as if the module was placed inside the app/ directory but this does not work as the import fails. I know that imports in python don't work like this, and tried it after reading the same question at [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure) which appears to be outdated. I have also read that using python -m unittest should work provided that the test cases are in a /test directory and named test_*.py, but this did not work either, and outputs "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s".

So far the only way I'm able to use my unit tests is to move them to the app/ directory each time I want to run them. Would anybody be able to advise me on the how to use unittests in a separate directory like this without moving them to the app/ directory or importing them with a separate test module permanently inside the app/ directory?

Comment: show the error you're getting when running test from the test directory.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module', is there something I'm missing to add the app/ directory to the path when running the tests?

Comment: post the error that you're getting in your original post so that others can also read it.

Comment: also include in your post the import that you're doing in your `test_MyPackage.py` file and how you're running your test.

Answer (score 0):

This is working now, I added an `__init__.py` file in the test/ directory and the tests all ran successfully when using python -m unittest. I thought this file wasn't required after Python 3.3 but it appears that unittest doesn't work correctly without it