# Use unittest to run tests from function

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-module

I have a Python module `foo` with the following layout:

```
foo
├── __init__.py
└── test.py
```

`test.py` contains a number of test, i.e.:

```
import unittest

class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now, I'd like to be able to run these tests either by running `test.py` or by calling a function `foo.test`. To make the latter possible I added the following to `__init__.py`:

```
import unittest

from .test import *

def test():
    unittest.main()
```

This works but it pollutes `foo` with the tests defined in `test.py`. How can I avoid this? I.e. I don't want someone using `foo` to be able to see/use `foo.FooTest`.

Comment: Are you worried about security or namespace confusion or something else? That is, why not move `test.py` to a subdirectory `foo/test/test.py` following the advice here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885/2541138?