# How to fix discovery of module-under-test in test code with unittest?

Tags: python, python-import, python-unittest

I've been struggling with this error and I have no idea of why it happens.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lambdaFunction'

This is the folder structure.

[image: Folder Structure]

And for some reason when I try to run the lambda_unit_test.py it keeps failing.

This is the code in there:

```
import unittest
from lambdaFunction import index


class LambdaTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def lambda_returns_Rick_Sanchez(self):
        self.assertEquals(index.lambda_handlerx(), "Should return Rick Sanchez")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I've also tried things like `import lambdaFunction` without any luck.

These are the command line outputs:

```
python3 -m unittest test.lambda_unit_test.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: lambda_unit_test (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: lambda_unit_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.lambda_unit_test'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

If I try running `python3 -m unittest test.lambda_unit_test` from the root folder it does not run any test:

```
python3 -m unittest test.lambda_unit_test  

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

Comment: How are you running the test?

Comment: @drum I tried with ```python lambda_unit_test.py``` and also tried with ```python -m unittest```this last one does not run any test.

Comment: @GinoMempin no :( I tried the same and still got that error

Comment: From *where* or *which folder* are you running `python -m unittest` ? The unittest module needs to find both your module and your tests. Please [edit] to show the command line outputs.

Comment: @GinoMempin I'm running it from the test folder, what I've tried to do as well is this:
python3 -m unittest test.lambda_unit_test.py
```E
ERROR: lambda_unit_test (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
ImportError: Failed to import test module: lambda_unit_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.lambda_unit_test'


Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your attempts and any other details *into the question*. It's hard to follow and read codes and console log in the comments. I'll help you get the formatting right.

Comment: Oh, I tried changing the folder name. Because unittest apparently is looking for a folder named test. Let me edit that

Comment: You need to add the module to your `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

### Problem 1

The **1st problem** is the "*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lambdaFunction'*", which is usually caused by how you are running `unittest`. As described in [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1896918/2745495) (specifically, [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885/2745495)), you have to make sure `unittest` finds both your modules-under-test and the test files.

So, given

```
myproject
├── lambdaFunction
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── index.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── lambda_unit_test.py
```

You run `unittest` under the `myproject` folder:

```
$ cd myproject
$ python3 -m unittest discover
```

That would tell `unittest` to use its [Test Discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) feature to find your test files and test methods. That would *also* automatically fix your import paths (`sys.path`), so that your tests would be able to import your modules, without you needing to hack around `sys.path`.

If the discovery works correctly, then `from lambdaFunction import index` should be fine, without any [modifications to `sys.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65651998/2745495), which can easily break when renaming and moving around files and folders.

### Problem 2

The **2nd problem** is naming, specifically the names of your test files and names of your test methods. They don't follow the default patterns used by `TestLoader.discover()` which is used in Test Discovery:

1. `lambda_unit_test.py`

   - By default, `unittest` looks for files matching the pattern `test*.py`
   - As to why, see the [discover(start_dir, pattern='test*.py', top_level_dir=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) method of `unittest`'s [TestLoader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) class, which is "*used to create test suites from classes and modules*".
2. `lambda_returns_Rick_Sanchez`

   - By default, `unittest` looks for methods that start with `test` (ex. `test_function`).
   - As to why, see the [testMethodPrefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.testMethodPrefix) attribute of `unittest`'s [TestLoader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader.discover) class, which is a "*string giving the prefix of method names which will be interpreted as test methods. The default value is 'test'.*"

If you just run `python3 -m unittest discover` as is, expect to get "*Ran 0 tests*". You can [specify the exact test to run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface), skipping the Test Discovery pattern problems, by passing in `test_module.TestClass.test_method`:

```
$ python3 -m unittest test.lambda_unit_test.LambdaTest.lambda_returns_Rick_Sanchez
```

But that's not a good solution. One option to fix this is to simply follow the default patterns used by Test Discovery. Rename your test files and test methods like so:

1. `lambda_unit_test.py` --> `test_lambda_functions.py`
2. `lambda_returns_Rick_Sanchez` --> `test_lambda_returns_Rick_Sanchez`

```
$ python3 -m unittest discover -v
test_lambda_returns_Rick_Sanchez (test.test_lambda_functions.LambdaTest) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

If you *really* want to use custom test file names and/or test method names, you will have to customize the test loader. See the [load_tests Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) section of the docs:

> Modules or packages can customize how tests are loaded from them during normal test runs or test discovery by implementing a function called `load_tests`.

There are a number of ways to implement `load_tests`, one way is to add a `load_tests` function in your `test/__init__.py` file, as instructed in the [load_tests Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol):

> If discovery is started in a directory containing a package, either from the command line or by calling `TestLoader.discover()`, then the package `__init__.py` will be checked for `load_tests`.

```py
# In test/__init__.py

from pathlib import Path
from unittest import TestSuite

def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    suite = TestSuite()
    loader.testMethodPrefix = 'lambda_returns'
    tests = loader.discover(
        Path(__file__).parent.as_posix(),
        pattern='*_test.py',
    )
    suite.addTests(tests)
    return suite
```

That code changes the method name prefix for tests to `lambda_returns` and to look for files with pattern `*_test.py`, both overriding the default behavior.

With that it should finally find your tests:

```
$ python3 -m unittest discover -v
lambda_returns_Rick_Sanchez (test.lambda_unit_test.LambdaTest) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

---

If you can, I highly recommend following instead the default patterns for test files and test method names. It's clearer (to me at least) and less code to maintain, the better.

As a side note, [`self.assertEquals` is now deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#deprecated-aliases). You should use instead `assertEqual`.

Comment: This helped me so much, I didn't know about the discover function nor how to change it and neither about the patterns. I'm just starting in unit testing and this was just enlightning, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```py
import unittest

#the two lines below make anything located two levels above this file importable
import os.path, sys; 
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__),*['..']*2))

from lambdaFunction import index
```