# How to get VSCode Python extension recognize submodules when running unittest test cases?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

**Problem**

I cannot get VSCode/unittest to recognize submodules (i.e., `common.nested_module` in the example in background) that I wrote unittests for.

VSCode discovers the tests cases and executes those in `test_my_module.py` but complains that there is no module `common.nested_module` on the `import` statement line in `test_nested_module.py` (in Output: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common.nested_module'`).

I added `print(sys.path)` to the executed test case and in Python Test log I even get the following output when adding `.env` file as described below in *What I tried 2.*:

```
test_get_version (test_my_module.TestCase1) ... ['/workspaces/test_project/project/tests', '/workspaces/test_project/project/src', '/workspaces/test_project/project/common', '/usr/local/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/vscode/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

**Background**

Following the [PyPA tutorial for packaging and distribution](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) I created a project structure, leaving out other details (e.g., `README.md`), as follows:

```
project
   |--src
      |--common
          |-- __init__.py
          |-- nested_module.py
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- my_module.py
   |--tests
      |--__init__.py
      |--test_my_module.py
      |--test_nested_module.py
```

Settings related to testing in `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "${workspaceFolder}/project/tests",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.cwd": "project/src",
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true,
}
```

**What I tried**

1. Adding the following to my `__init__.py` in `project/tests` as well as to `test_nested_module.py` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure).

```py
import os
import sys
PROJECT_PATH = os.getcwd()
SOURCE_PATH = os.path.join(
    PROJECT_PATH,"project/src/common"
)
sys.path.append(SOURCE_PATH)
```

2. Adding an `.env` to `project` containing the following while adding `"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/afinad/.env"` to `settings.json` similar to what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure).

```
PYTHONPATH = ./common
```

3. Adding `-t` option with `${workspaceFolder}/project/src` and `.` to `settings.json` for `python.testing.unittestArgs` as sggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6881):

```json
"python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "${workspaceFolder}/project/tests",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py",
        "-t",
        "${workspaceFolder}/project/src"
    ],
```

3. Running `python3 -m unittest discover` after changing into `./tests` in terminal gives me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'
```

**Thanks for taking time to read. Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: Does `{WorkspaceFolder}` point to `workspaces/test_project`?

Comment: @zerocukor287 Yes, it is resolved as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After nearly two days of trying different combinations of various suggested solutions I found my mistake. It seems, newbie as I am, that I felt for the [name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html).

Originally, I intended to have the same folder structure in `tests` as I had in `src`. However, when I figured that the `test_my_module.py` worked, I moved the `test_nested_module.py` from `tests/common` to `tests` but I did not remove the folder `tests/common`. This caused, as it seems, the `ModuleNotFoundError`, because after removing the folder, it works as expected.

I hope this will save others some time.