# Accessing module in parent folder

Tags: python, module

I was trying to implement something that I saw in a [tutorial on Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-typer-cli/). In the tutorial there a testing module (or do you call that a test file?) is in a directory `test/` and the code is in a directory `rptodo/`, and the test file imports the object to be tested with `from rptodo import __app_name__, __version__, cli`. This does not run by itself; an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rptodo'` occurs. But this does allow pytest to run the code. I then tried redoing this with my own example code and I get the same error even in pytest. What did I do wrong in creating the module?

My folder structure:

```
Anywhere
-here
--test_this.py
-there
--__init__.py
--yonder.py
```

yonder.py

```
class That:
    thing = 'something'
```

test_this.py

```
from there.yonder import That

def test_this():
    this = That()
    print(this.thing)

test_this()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer looking in one of stackoverflow's [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885/17532055), but this is so un-intuitive that I feel the need to post the answer here.

The folder with the test has to be made into a package by creating a file `__init__.py`. Pytest then knows to look at the parent folder for the module package that the required object is in.

Ironically, the folder being referenced does not need an `__init__.py` file to be found as a module for importing. Only the current folder making the call needs to be a module with `__init__.py` .

Not only when importing a module from a different folder, but even when accessing a module from the *current* folder, pytest needs the folder to have a `__init__.py` file to be able to import the files with the code for testing.