# Why is my user defined module not found by the test script?

Tags: python, python-module

I tried creating the user-defined module for my project but my script is getting failed with an error message

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Config'

The structure of my project is like this:

```
Project <Folder>
   |
   --- Config <Folder>
   |        |
   |        --- __init.py__
   |        --- Config.py
   --- Test cases
            |
            --- Testcase1.py
```

And the content of Testcase1.py is

```
import Config as config
print (config.main_url)
```

Comment: How do you execute `Testcase1.py`?

Comment: Do you expect `main_url` to be defined in `Config/__init__.py` or in `Config/Config.py`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 , I am just executing the file Testcase1.py using python.exe
and I tried both the cases Config/__init__.py and Config/Config.py none of them works for me

Comment: Yes, how exactly are you executing the file Testcase1.py using python.exe? What command do you type on the command line and what is your working directory?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I am executing the file below 

C:\Python37\python.exe C:\<path To file>\Testcase1.py

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure

Answer (score 0):

Your user-defined module should be in the same directory.