# Python module referencing issue

Tags: python, importerror, python-module, python-packaging

I have the below directory structure:

```
src/
--check.py
--quantum/
----__init__.py
----ansatz.py
----hva/
------__init__.py
------single_layer_hva.py
```

In my check.py, I'm doing the below:

```
#check.py
import quantum.ansatz as a

a.get_ansatz('sample_ansatz')
```

In my ansatz.py, I'm doing the below:

```
#ansatz.py
import hva.single_layer_hva as hva

single_layer_hva = hva.SingleLayerHVA()
```

In my single_layer_hva, I'm have defined a class I want to use in ansatz.py:

```
class SingleLayerHVA
```

There is no issue while executing ansatz.py and the modules are getting imported properly.

But, I'm getting the below error while executing check.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/high-fidelity-quantum-state-preparation/src/check.py", line 1, in <module>
    import quantum.ansatz as a
  File "/workspaces/high-fidelity-quantum-state-preparation/src/quantum/ansatz.py", line 4, in <module>
    import hva.single_layer_hva as hva
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hva'
```

I've tried following the steps mentioned in the below link, though it's not working.
https://iq-inc.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import/

Can someone suggest what can be done regarding this issue?

Comment: `from . hva import single_layer_hva as hva`?

Comment: check.py executes properly after making this change, though when I try to run ansatz.py, it gives me this error "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: Why do you Need a both to be executable? How are you executing them? `python3 -m src/quantum/ansatz.py` or something different?

Comment: I've got some tests within ansatz.py that I don't want to include in the check.py file. Executing both files through the run button on visual studio.

Comment: Put the tests in a separate hierarchy, called `/tests` next to `/src` and use fully qualified (not relative) package references (`import quantum.hva.single_layer_hva as hva`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71773830/running-unittest-using-a-src-package-directory-structure

Comment: One thing I noticed is that when I make changes in ansatz.py after making the suggested change and then running my check.py is that the module with the changes is not reflected in the code. I have to restart the kernel each time after I make a change in ansatz.py to see the change getting reflected in check.py.