# ModuleNotFoundError while running unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, pytest

With such a project structure:

```
- code
  - modules
    - tests
      test_data_quality_service.py
    data_quality_service.py
  - web
```

I keep getting errors when I try to import class DataQualityChecker from data_quality_service.
I get these erros both for absolute

```
from code.modules.data_quality_service import DataQualityChecker
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.modules'; 'code' is not a package
```

and relative imports:

```
from ..data_quality_service import DataQualityChecker
E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How can I fix it? It's happening in PyCharm, I'm running unit tests and I also tried pytest but I had the same error.

Comment: From wich directory are you executing the tests? Did you create `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've changed the project structure a little bit but only adding import sys
sys.path.append("..") before imports solved the problem

Comment: That means that you are executing the script in the wrong path. Try to execute the script from the root of the project

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an [`__init__.py` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for#:%7E:text=The%20__init__.py%20file%20makes%20Python%20treat%20directories,the%20submodules%20to%20be%20exported.) (it can be empty) on each folder to mark it as a python package.

```
- code
  - modules
    - tests
      test_data_quality_service.py
      __init__.py
    data_quality_service.py
    __init__.py
  - web
```

---

Also, probably you should consider a better [project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

Comment: I tried that as well but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In python installation directory there is file python38._pth
You have to give module path code.modules

Comment: This can be done with the flag -m when executing the python script. Btw, with an IDE as pycharm this is not necesary if you use it to execute the code