# Python unittests used in a project structure with multiple directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I need to use `unittest` python library to execute tests about the 3 functions in `src/arithmetics.py` file. Here is my project structure.

```
.
├── src
│   └── arithmetics.py
└── test
    └── lcm
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── test_lcm_exception.py
        └── test_lcm.py
```

`src/arithmetics.py`

```py
def lcm(p, q):
    p, q = abs(p), abs(q)
    m = p * q
    while True:
        p %= q
        if not p:
            return m // q
        q %= p
        if not q:
            return m // p

def lcm_better(p, q):
    p, q = abs(p), abs(q)
    m = p * q
    h = p % q
    while h != 0:
        p = q
        q = h
        h = p % q
    h = m / q
    return h

def lcm_faulty(p, q):
    r, m = 0, 0
    r = p * q
    while (r > p) and (r > q):
        if (r % p == 0) and (r % q == 0):
            m = r
        r = r - 1
    return m
```

`test/lcm/test_lcm.py`

```py
import unittest
from src.arithmetics import *

class LcmTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_lcm(self):
        for X in range(1, 100):
            self.assertTrue(0 == lcm(0, X))
            self.assertTrue(X == lcm(X, X))

        self.assertTrue(840 == lcm(60, 168))
    
    def test_lcm_better(self):
        for X in range(1, 100):
            self.assertTrue(0 == lcm_better(0, X))
            self.assertTrue(X == lcm_better(X, X))
    
        self.assertTrue(840 == lcm_better(60, 168))
    
    def test_lcm_faulty(self):
        self.assertTrue(0 == lcm_faulty(0, 0))
    
        for X in range(1, 100):
            self.assertTrue(0 == lcm_faulty(X, 0))
            self.assertTrue(0 == lcm_faulty(0, X))
    
        self.assertTrue(840 == lcm_faulty(60, 168))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

`test/lcm/test_lcm_exception.py`

```py
import unittest
from src.arithmetics import *

class LcmExceptionTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_lcm_exception(self):
        for X in range(0, 100):
            self.assertTrue(0 == lcm(0, 0))         # ZeroDivisionError
            self.assertTrue(0 == lcm(X, 0))         # ZeroDivisionError

    def test_lcm_better_exception(self):
        for X in range(0, 100):
            self.assertTrue(0 == lcm_better(0, 0))  # ZeroDivisionError
            self.assertTrue(0 == lcm_better(X, 0))  # ZeroDivisionError
    
    def test_lcm_faulty_exception(self):
        for X in range(1, 100):
            self.assertTrue(X == lcm_faulty(X, X))  # ppcm(1, 1) != 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

`test/lcm/__init__.py` is an empty file

To execute my tests, I tried this command :
`python3 -m unittest discover`

But the output is :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I don't understand how can I run my tests...

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A file `__init__.py` is missing

I think that the problem is the missing of file `__init__.py` in the folder `test`. Try to add this (empty) file in that folder as I show you below:

```
test_lcm
├── src
│   └── arithmetics.py
└── test
    └── __init__py    <---------------- add this file
    └── lcm
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── test_lcm_exception.py
        └── test_lcm.py
```

If you watch my tree folders I have created a folder `test_lcm` as root of the tree. You have to execute the `cd` command to place yourself inside that  folder.
So execute a `cd` command similar to the following (in my system `test_lcm` is placed in my home folder):

```
# go to test_lcm folder
cd ~/test_lcm
```

After that, execute:

```
# execute test
python3 -m unittest discover
```

The last part of the output is:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=2)
```

The output shows that are executed 6 tests with 2 errors (`test_lcm_better_exception` and `test_lcm_exception` fail).

#### Useful links

- [This](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) is a useful link to know how to define a Python package.

In particular I want to highlight the following sentence present in that link:

> **The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages.**

- Instead [this is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure) which speaks of a similar topic.
- Furthermore [this link](https://dev.to/methane/don-t-omit-init-py-3hga) reports this sentence:

> For example, unittest module in standard library doesn't search into directory without `__init__.py`.

This explains why the file `__init__.py` is necessary. May be in the future the `unittest` module will search tests also in directories without `__init__.py` file.