# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named src when running tests with VS Code Testing Tab

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, directory-structure

I have a Project with the following (simplified) folder-structure

```
- my_project/
  - src/
    - core/
      - core.py
      - __init__.py
    - other/
      - other.py
      - __init__.py
    - models/
      - myModel.py
      - __init__.py
  - test/
    - unit/
      - test_core.py
      - __init__.py
    - integration/
      - test_all.py
      - __init__.py
```

All the `__init__.py` files were added in an attempt to solve the problem. test_all.py and test_core.py both have `from src.models.myModel import myModel` because I need myModel in the test.
I can run the all tests (test_core and test_all) by running `python -m pytest` in the terminal at `my_project`. The tests all get executed and I get the report of successes and failures.

One of my tests doesn't work how it should, so I wanted to debug it. For that, I tried using the testing tab in VS Code. It asks me to "configure python tests, where I choose the following options: test framework: pytest, directory containing the tests: test. This leads to the following settings.json file:

```json
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./test",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "test"
    ]
}
```

I then get the following Error in the testing tab:

```
______ ERROR collecting test/integration/test_all.py ______
ImportError while importing test module 'path/to/test_all.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test\integration\test_all.py:4: in <module>
    from src.models.myModel import myModel
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
______________ ERROR collecting test/unit/test_core.py ______________
ImportError while importing test module 'path/to/test_core.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test\unit\test_core.py:2: in <module>
    from src.models.myModel import myModel
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR test/integration/test_all.py
ERROR test/unit/test_core.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 2 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
==================== no tests collected, 2 errors in 0.20s ====================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Domin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    main(tool, cmd, subargs, toolargs)
  File "c:\Users\Domin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\__main__.py", line 99, in main
    parents, result = run(toolargs, **subargs)
  File "c:\Users\Domin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\pythonFiles\testing_tools\adapter\pytest\_discovery.py", line 47, in discover
    raise Exception("pytest discovery failed (exit code {})".format(ec))
Exception: pytest discovery failed (exit code 2)

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Domin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.10.1\out\client\extension.js:2:241783)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1121:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)]
```

Why does `python -m pytest work, but the testing tab in VS Code not?`
I am grateful for all the help I can get, since I've been stuck with this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must add at least the empty file `__init__.py` in the folder `src`, so that *this folder can be threat as package*.
I'm not sure adding this file can be enough to solve your problem with VS Code, but in my system if I execute the following commands:

```
> cd /path/to/my_project

> python -m pytest
```

without the `__init__.py` file in `src` the output of the execution with pytest is:

```
========================= test session starts =========================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.17, pytest-4.6.11, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/my_project
collected 0 items / 2 errors                                                   

========================= ERRORS =========================
_________________ ERROR collecting test/integrate/test_all.py __________________
ImportError while importing test module '/path/to/my_project/test/integrate/test_all.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/integrate/test_all.py:2: in <module>
    from src.models.myModel import myModel
E   ImportError: No module named src.models.myModel
___________________ ERROR collecting test/unit/test_core.py ____________________
ImportError while importing test module '/path/to/my_project/test/unit/test_core.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/unit/test_core.py:2: in <module>
    from src.models.myModel import myModel
E   ImportError: No module named src.models.myModel
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 2 errors during collection !!!!
```

So your folder structure must become:

```
- my_project/
  - src/
    - __init__.py    <----- add this file
    - core/
      - core.py
      - __init__.py
    - other/
      - other.py
      - __init__.py
    - models/
      - myModel.py
      - __init__.py
  - test/
    - unit/
      - test_core.py
      - __init__.py
    - integration/
      - test_all.py
      - __init__.py
```

By the adding of the `__init__.py` file the pytest execution has the following output:

```
========================= test session starts =========================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.17, pytest-4.6.11, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/my_project
collected 2 items

test/integrate/test_all.py .                               [50%]
test/unit/test_core.py .
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655669/python-unittests-used-in-a-project-structure-with-multiple-directories/74657488#74657488) is related to the same topic and could be an other useful example for you.

---

**Note about PyCharm and VSC**
I use PyCharm as IDE for Python and with this IDE I need to add the folder `my_project` to the `Project Structure` (by the Settings menu of the project) to be able to execute the test inside your `test_all.py` and `test_core.py` without the import error.

I don't know if this answer could be enaugh for you, but I'm sorry: I can't test your code in my system by VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate the help. That's weird, because for me doing `python -m pytest` in the my_project folder without an `__init__.py` in `src` worked and didn't give me the ImportError that you got.
Even weirder, when I started up my computer today, the testing tab in VS Code showed all the tests and let me execute them right from the testing tab. The ImportError that I had previously gotten is gone now, even though I didn't change anything.