# unittest directory structure - cannot import src code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have the following folder structure in my project:

```
my-project
   src/
       __init__.py
       script.py
   test/
       __init__.py
       test_script.py
```

Ideally I want to have a separate folder where all the unit tests go. My `test_script.py` looks something like this:

```
from src.script import my_object

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_script_object(self):
        # unit test here
        pass

if __name__ == 'main':
    unittest.main()
```

When I try to run the script (using `python test_script.py`) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from src.script import my_object
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I was following the instructions [from this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure), and I even tried appending `src` to the sys path (which forces me to change how I do imports in the rest of the project). When I'm not trying to append to the sys path, both of my `__init__.py` files are empty.

I am using python 3.8.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm new to unit testing in python, so maybe there is a better structure or other conventions I'm not aware of. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "_Does anyone have any suggestions?_" This site is for _complete_ answers to _precise_, on-topic questions. Can you please ask a precise question? You can see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: It worked for me when I fixed the pythonpath. And I also fixed the extra ".py" in the import line, but that can't be there with the error messages you got, so I don't think you're showing us the code you ran. So ... you said "sys path" which I hope doesn't mean system path.

Comment: @starball thanks for more specific Meta reference questions; I added them to my saves.

Comment: That directory layout looks a little suspect...in particular, having `src/__init__.py` looks odd, because do you really want `src` to be an importable module?

Comment: also, `from src.script.py import my_object` is an invalid import statement; you don't include the `.py` extension on `import`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, any instructions that have you modifying `sys.path` in order to run your tests are sending you in the wrong direction. Your testing tool should be able to discover both your tests and your application code without requiring that sort of hackery.

I generally use [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/) for running my tests. I would structure your example like this:

```
my-project/
├── src
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── myproject
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── script.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_script.py
```

Assuming that `src/myproject/script.py` looks like this:

```
def double(x: int):
    return x*2
```

And `tests/test_script.py` look like this:

```
import myproject.script

def test_double():
    res = myproject.script.double(2)
    assert res == 4
```

I can run tests from the `my-project` directory by simply running `pytest`:

```
$ pytest
========================================== test session starts ==========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python/my-project
collected 1 item

tests/test_script.py .                                                                            [100%]

=========================================== 1 passed in 0.00s ===========================================
```

In this setup, the file `src/conftest.py` is what allows pytest to automatically discover the location of your application code. Alternatively, you could instead specify that in your `pyproject.toml` file like this:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  "src"
]
```

pytest also works if you write `unittest`-style tests as you show in your question; the above behavior would be identical if `tests/test_script.py` looked like:

```
import unittest
import myproject.script

class TestScript(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_double(self):
        res = myproject.script.double(2)
        self.assertEqual(res, 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

(But I prefer pytest's simpler syntax.)

Possibly useful reading:

- [Good integration practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html)

---

If you really want to use `unittest` you *can* use the same directory layout, but you will need to update `sys.path` for it to run correctly. The easiest way to do that is:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PWD/src python -m unittest
```

This will automatically discover all your tests and run them. You can run a single test like this:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PWD/src python -m tests.test_script
```

You can avoid needing to modify `sys.path` if you use a simpler directory layout:

```
my-project/
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_script.py
```

Both `pytest` and `python -m unittest`, when run from the `my-project` directory, will correctly discover and run your tests without requiring any path modifications.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to run from the /test/ directory (rookie mistake) and now I am able to run my tests with just `python -m unittest`. I read through the article you linked and will definitely consider switching to pytest. Thanks for your help!