# Import problems in python unittest

Tags: python, python-import, python-unittest

I'm new to python and trying to get a unittest working, but the imports in the test files don't work.
Folder structure:

```
toyProjects
└── pythonProj
    ├── mainpack
    │   ├── __init__.py         
    │   ├── MyClass.py  
    │   └── setup.py
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py        
        └── test_MyClass.py
```

MyClass.py:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def someMethod(self):
        print("Called MyClass.someMethod");
```

setup.py:

```
def myFunction():
    print("Called setup.myFunction");
```

test_MyClass.py:

```
import unittest

import setup
from MyClass import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.my = MyClass(4);

    def test_something(self):
        self.my.someMethod();
        setup.myFunction();
```

Incase it matters: there is a mainfile.py in pythonProj (not shown in the diagram above cause I assume it's not relevant) which runs fine and finds all the files. Its contents are:

```
from mainpack import setup
from mainpack.MyClass import MyClass

print("Program start");

setup.myFunction()

myInst = MyClass(4);
myInst.someMethod();
```

I run the test with

```
cd toyProjects\pythonProj\tests
python -m unittest test_MyClass.py
```

I tried pretty much all the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure). And [this page](https://iq-inc.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import/) says "Many resources on the web will have you fiddling with your sys.path but in most cases, this is a code smell that indicates you are not properly using modules and/or packages.", so hopefully I can learn the proper way to do it (but I'll use sys.path if there's no other solution. Only so far, all the versions I've tried of that haven't worked either.)

More specifically, different types of imports I tried in the test_MyClass file:

```
import setup                               -->ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setup'
from MyClass import MyClass                -->ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyClass'
from mainpack import setup                 -->ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mainpack'
from ..mainpack import setup               -->Unresolved reference mainpack
import mainpack                            -->ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mainpack'
from mainpack.setup import someFunction    -->Unresolved reference mainpack
from .. import mainpack                    -->ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Put an empty `__init__.py` in `pythonProj`, then things like `from ..mainpack import setup` and `from .. import mainpack` *should* work.

Comment: @MattDMo : Didn't work. Both still give "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Answer (score 4):

For a package to be importable, it has to be located in one of the directories specified by your `PATH` environment variable. Since you don't have the `pythonProj` directory in your `PATH`, you can instead run the script from that directory because python automatically adds the current working directory to `PATH` when running a script.

Because the `setup` and `MyClass` modules are not reachable from `PATH`, they cannot be imported using implicit relative imports. Instead, you can use absolute imports in `test_MyClass.py`:
`import setup` -> `from mainpack import setup`
`from MyClass import MyClass` -> `from mainpack.MyClass import MyClass`

Then you can run your tests:

```
cd toyProjects/pythonProj
python -m unittest tests/test_MyClass.py
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thanks!
Is this the common practice though, for people who have lots of projects?

Comment: I can't say if it's common or not, but this should be easier than having to tweak PATH for every project.