# Why it can not find the package from subfolder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I met a strange problem in python package. I have a python package named manchinetranslator in which I created a subfolder for unit tests as shown below.

```
manchinetranslator/translator.py
manchinetranslator/__init__.py
manchinetranslator/tests/tests.py
```

In translator.py, two functions are defined as:

```
def english_to_french(text):
...
def french_to_english(text):
...
```

The **init**.py is:

`from . import translator`

The tests.py contains unit tests of the two functions in translator.py and is as follows:

```
import unittest
from translator import english_to_french, french_to_english
class Test_english_to_french(unittest.TestCase):
...   
class Test_french_to_english(unittest.TestCase):
...
```

But when running tests.py, it gives an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\manchinetranslator\tests\tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from manchinetranslator.translator import english_to_french, french_to_english
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manchinetranslator'
```

However, when tests.py is put in the same folder as translator.py, it works fine. I guess it may need to set $PYTHONPATH, but I am not sure how to do it. So I need help with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to import from the parent directory, that won't work. `tests.py` cannot import from `translator` because it is inside it.

See this SO answer instead for what to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266885/30581

Comment: What should be included in the __init__.py in tests folder? There is no module to import in the tests folder, only a unit test file that is not called.

Comment: You can leave it blank. Even though it is blank, it has to exist. I added this info to my answer. You can read more information here: https://crunchingthedata.com/python-init-file/

Comment: Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: No, it does not work with the same error.

Comment: Oh you are trying to import a method from the parent directory. That's not possible. I changed my answer

Comment: By the link of @OneCricketeer, it confirms my guess. The subfolder must be in the sys.path because "When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on sys.path looking for the package subdirectory.".

Comment: @user103 see my answer, I updated it to point to another SO answer.