# Not able to debug unittest in vscode for python

Tags: python, python-unittest, vscode-debugger

I am able to Run unittest for python in vscode, but not debug it. what did I do wrong?

Structure:

```
myproject
  \mymodule
      \matrix.py
  \test
      \matrix_test.py
```

in matrix_test.py:

```
import unittest
from mymodule import matrix
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
def test_convert(self):
    self.assertEqual('abc', matrix.convert('abc'))
```

I am getting error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

Comment: The very common directory structure for even a simple Python module seems to be to separate the unit tests into their own test directory.