# Is it possible to run all unit test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have two module with two different classes and their corresponding test classes.

```
 foo.py
 ------
 class foo(object):
     def fooMethod(self):
         // smthg

 bar.py
 ------
 class bar(object):
     def barMethod(self):
         // smthg

 fooTest.py
 ------
 class fooTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def fooMethodTest(self):
         // smthg

 barTest.py
 ------
 class barTest(unittest.TestCase):
     def barMethodTest(self):
         // smthg
```

In any, test and source module, file, I **erased** the `if __name__ == "__main__":` because of increasing coherency and obeying object-oriented ideology.

Like in Java unit test, I'm looking for creating a module to run all unittest. For example,

```
 runAllTest.py
 -------------
 class runAllTest(unittest.TestCase):
    ?????

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    ?????
```

I looked for search engine but didn't find any tutorial or example. Is it possible to do so? Why? or How?

*Note: I'm using eclipse and pydev distribution on windows machine.*

Comment: I would rename the test files to 'test_foo.py' format, and run `nosetests` in the test directory. `nose` will autodiscover all the test files and test classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a [`TestSuite`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code) and run all your tests in it's `if __name__ == '__main__'` block:

```
import unittest   

def create_suite():
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(fooTest())
    test_suite.addTest(barTest())
    return test_suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
   suite = create_suite()

   runner=unittest.TextTestRunner()
   runner.run(suite)
```

If you do not want to create the test cases manually look at [this quesiton/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732477/342473), which basically creates the test cases dynamically, or use some of the features of the `unittest` module like [test discovery](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) feature and [command line](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) options ..

Answer (score 13):

When running unit tests based on the built-in python unittest module, at the root level of your project run

```
python -m unittest discover <module_name>
```

For the specific example above, it suffices to run

```
python -m unittest discover .
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

Comment: By far the best, most concise approach on here. Good tip, @mcguip

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the [TestLoader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader). With this you can load specific tests or modules or load everything under a given directory. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732438/how-to-run-all-python-unit-tests-in-a-directory) post has some useful examples using a `TestSuite` instance.

EDIT: The code I usually have in my test.py:

```
if not popts.tests:
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/tests')
    #print(suite._tests)

    # Print outline
    lg.info(' * Going for Interactive net tests = '+str(not tvars.NOINTERACTIVE))

    # Run
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=popts.verbosity).run(suite)
else:
    lg.info(' * Running specific tests')

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()

    # Load standard tests
    for t in popts.tests:
        test = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromName("tests."+t)
        suite.addTest(test)

    # Run
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=popts.verbosity).run(suite)
```

Does two things:

1. If -t flag (tests) is not present, find and load all tests in directory
2. Else, load the requested tests one-by-one

Answer (score 2):

I think you could just run the following command under the folder where your tests files are located:

```
python -m unittest
```

as mentioned here in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) that "when executed without arguments Test Discovery is started"

Answer (score 1):

With [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/) right click on a folder in Eclipse and choose "Run as-> Python unit-test". This will run all tests in that folder (the names of the test files and methods have to start with "test_".)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [nosetests](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

You *might* need to rename your files; I'm not sure about the pattern nose uses to find the test files but, personally, I use `*_test.py`. It is possible to specify a custom pattern which your project uses for test filenames but I remember being unable to make it work so I ended up renaming my tests instead.

You also need to follow [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) conventions to work with nose. I don't use IDEs with Python but your IDE may already follow it---just read the PEP and check.

With a PEP 328 directory/package structure, you can run individual tests as

```
nosetests path.to.class_test
```

Note that instead of the usual directory separators (`/` or `\`), I used dots.

To run *all* tests, simply invoke `nosetests` at the root of your project.