# Python project structure and relative imports

Tags: python, python-import, project-structure, relative-import

I'm new to Python and I searched google a lot and read some articles about relative imports etc. Despite the fact that I am unable to get it working. Please, consider my following project structure:

```
/Project
    /docs
    /log
    /prev
    /src
        a.py
    /tests
        /tests1
            b.py
        /tests2
    .gitignore
    README.txt
    program.py
```

And what I'm trying to achieve is to import a class from file `a.py` inside of the script `b.py`. Generally speaking, script `b.py` should have line with import of `a.py`. I've read some articles about using `__init__.py` files, where should I put them? And should I change `PYTHONPATH` some way, how? And last question, is project structure OK? Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Have a look at e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/ - you should write a `setup.py` and *install* your package for import by the tests. The `/tests` directory itself isn't usually a module (so no `__init__.py`) - see https://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#goodpractises

Comment: @jonrsharpe "the /tests directory itself isn't usually a module" - do you mean package rather than module there?

Comment: @TomDalton yes, package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Python unit tests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) and you can start with [how-do-i-run-all-python-unit-tests-in-a-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732438/how-do-i-run-all-python-unit-tests-in-a-directory).