# Python Project Structure, Imports

Tags: python

I have the following python project setup:

```
/project
    /doc
    /config
        some_config.json
    /src
        /folderA
            __init__.py
            Databaseconnection.py
            ...
        /folderB
            __init__.py
            Calculator.py
            ...
        /main
            __init__.py
            Main.py
            ...
        /test
            __init__.py
            AnImportantTest.py
        __init__.py
    .gitignore
    README.md
    requirements.txt
```

`Main.py` is the "executable file" (or rather module) that calls all the other modules. All `__init__.py` files are empty. **How are the import statements in Main.py supposed to look like?** I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732916/python-project-structure-and-relative-imports), which was not very helpful however:

```
# Main.py

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'../..')

from folderA.Databaseconnection import *      # not working
from src.folderA.Databaseconnection import *  # not working
```

Thank you.

Comment: I would move `Main.py` (should be lowercase) up to `/src`, which will simplify the imports, and put the `/tests` in a separate directory under `/project`. As it stands, you need `..` to go "up" one directory in your `import`s, rather than hacking the path.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sys.path.insert()` gives python another directory  to look at for modules to import. The directory `../../` adds the folder `/project`, but that is not where the modules exist. Use this instead:

```
# Main.py

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'../') # /src

from folderA.Databaseconnection import *
```