# How to organize project structure of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a project named `myproject`. In `myproject` directory. there are `other` sub-directory and `main.py`. And in `other` sub-directory, there are `a.py` and `b.py`.

The content in `a.py` is

```
import b
```

The content in `main.py` is:

```
from other.a import *
```

Here comes a problem, in `main.py`, when I use `from other.a import *`, the the content of `a.py` is included in `main.py`, it will raise an error, because `b.py` is in `other`, so in `main.py` using `import b` is wrong, and we should use `import other.b`, but `a.py` needs `import b`, so it is contradictory. How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python project structure and relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732916/python-project-structure-and-relative-imports)

Comment: @MartinAlonso The question you linked is very different from this one.

Comment: You should not use relative imports inside packages.  In Python 3, they don't work, and in Python 2 they are deprecated.  So in `a.py` you need to do `from . import b` or `import other.b`.

Comment: And don't mess with `sys.path`, as suggested in the other question.  It's sometimes helpful for testing, and special circumstances, but in general you are better off leaving the management of `sys.path` to distribution utilities.

Comment: @SvenMarnach But `a.py` need `import b`, if I use `import other.b` in `a.py`, when I run `a.py`, it also will raise a error.

Comment: @Gauss If `a.py` is part of a package, it can't be run dicrectly.  That's intended.  Modules in a package are supposed to provide functions and classes for use by other parts of the program, but they are not supposed to have side effects when imported.
In some circumstances it's useful to make a module directly runnable, but you would need to run it using `python -m other.a`.  However, this is an advanced approach for special situations.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your code structure, correct?

```python
mypackage
    other
        __init__.py
        a.py # import b
        b.py # def func_b()
    __init__.py
    main.py # from other.a import *
```

You can use this code structure:

DON'T USE ABSOLUTE IMPORT in your installable package such as: `from mypackage.other import b` in `main.py`, Use relative import such as: `from .other import b` in `main.py`.

```python
mypackage
    other
        __init__.py
        a.py # from . import b
        b.py
    __init__.py
    main.py # from .other.a import *
```

then you can do this in main.py:

```python
b.func_b(...)
```

Because by doing this, when you have a script `test.py`

```python
from mypackage import main

main.b.func_b()
```

underlying it does `from .other.a import *`, because you have `from . import b` in `a.py`. so the `*` is actually `b`, that's why you can use `b.func_b()` `in main.py`.