# How to run all tests with one shell command?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Suppose I've got a few modules with test cases derived from `unittest.TestCase`. All those modules reside in one package `test`:

```
test/
   test_case1.py
   test_case2.py
   test_case3.py
```

I'd like to run *all* tests in all modules in `test` with *one* shell command. In order to do it I've added a new module `test_all.py`, which creates a `TestSuite` with all the test cases, and `main`:

```
def make_suite():
  ... # add test cases explicitly one by one

if __name__ == "__main__":
  suite = make_suite()
  unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Now I wonder if there is a way to run *all* the test cases in `test` without making a `TestSuite`

Comment: Are you opposed to using a tool like `nosetests`?

Comment: Yes if it is not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in Python 2.7, you can do something like this:

```
python -m unittest discover <test_directory>
```

Of course, all your test directories must contain an `__init__.py` file.

You can also use a tool like [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to run your tests.

See also:

- [How do I run all Python unit tests in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732438/how-do-i-run-all-python-unit-tests-in-a-directory)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `discover` solution is probably what I need.

Comment: Great. If it ends up working, I hope you'll accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in ./test/test_case*.py; do python $f; done
```