# In Eclipse, how do I execute all files in a folder using py.test?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, pytest

I have a folder containing several files starting with "test_" that each contain tests. How do I execute all the files, using py.test, under a single run, with Eclipse?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732438/how-do-i-run-all-python-unit-tests-in-a-directory

Comment: Not really, it isn't Eclipse or pytest specific.

Comment: you want to do this programmatically or can use UI

Comment: I want to do it via Eclipse interface

Comment: Here you go, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on Parent/Test `module`, select `Run As` and then select `Python unit-test`. It will run all the test cases which starts with `test_` of that module [image]

Comment: As a note, in your pyunit preferences, you may have to select to use pytest (as the default is using the unittest runner).

Comment: To clarify: the names of the test files and test methods have to start with "test_"