# Python - Running unit and integration tests with standard directory structure

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have the following directory structure, as recommended in [the pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html#goodpractices) :

```
setup.py
src/
    mypkg/
        __init__.py            
        app.py
        view.py
tests/
    __init__.py                 
    unit/
        __init__.py
        app_test.py
    integration/
        __init__.py
        app_test.py
```

All **init**.py files are empty for now.

And setup.py contains:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name="mypkg", packages=find_packages())
```

I want to use [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/) for testing.

The command i use to run tests is

```sh
 pytest ./tests/unit/app_test.py
```

How do I import `app.py` into `app_test.py` and make sure my tests can run without issue.

Ideally, I want a pythonic/clean way to resolve this, not a hack.

I've stumbled upon many questions in regards to this, such as :
[How do I run all Python unit tests in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732438/how-do-i-run-all-python-unit-tests-in-a-directory?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)

But somehow I can't get it to work with my use case. Can anybody pinpoint in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I got what i was looking for with :

```
setup.py
src/
    main.py
    __init__.py

tests/
    __init__.py                 
    unit/
        __init__.py
        app_test.py
    integration/
        __init__.py
        app_test.py
```

In app_test.py simply,

```py
  import src.main
```

Running tests with :

```sh
pytest  ./tests/unit/app_test.py
```